# How do you declare this macro in lex?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I'm new to Lex and I'm confused on how to declare the following macro, keyword. I want keyword to consist of either "if", "then", "else", or "while."

I typed this in lex:

```
keyword                   "if" | "then" | "else" | "while"
```

but the compiler is giving me an "unrecognized rule error". When I instead do

```
keyword                   "if"
```

It compiles ok.

Is this just a limitation of Lex? I know in jflex you can do what I did above and it'll work fine. Or am I doing it incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: In flex, you cannot put spaces in a regex. (If you want to match a literal space, you need to quote it.) There is no need to quote keywords but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: You don't want to do this at all. The parser needs to know *which* keyword. You need to return a different value for each one.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now, but off the top of my head:

Try putting the values in parentheses (before the first %%)

```
keyword                   ("if"|"then"|"else"|"while")
```

And then use it in rules like this (between %% and %%):

```
{keyword}   {//action}
```

This is how you make a class in lex, so in the rest of the code you can use `{keyword}` and it will be recognized as the regex you've assigned in the definition section (before the first %%).
Also, you can use a class as a part of other regexs:

```
{keyword}\{[^\}]\}   {//action}
```

This recognizes a whole block of code. (but it doesn't check the syntax inside the block, I leave that to you :) )

Comment: The parentheses are not necessary. Never seen `\\action`: what's that?

Comment: He would like to say "`{keyword}   {` action-in-italics `}`", but was constrained by the markdown.

Comment: I meant a piece of code you write when lex finds your token, not literally action :)